# Is it safe to catch an Exception object

Tags: scala, exception, casting

I use a Java lib that relies on exceptions. Simplified code below:

```scala
    try {
      val eventTime = eventTimeString.as[Date]
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        logger.error(s"Can't parse eventTime from $eventTimeString", e)
        // take action for the bad Date string.
    }
```

In Java I would catch only the exception from parsing a string into a Date, letting the rest go uncaught since they could be fatal. Here my understanding is that catching `Exception` means to catch ANY non-fatal/non-serious exceptions. Since it is not the same a catching `Throwable` it is safe—but is it truly? The rationale for using this is that unknown exceptions might be thrown from deeper in the stack and if they are not fatal, why not catch all of them. This has always been a problem in Java where it is easy to find possible exceptions from the direct call you are making but not from deeper. Is this the Scala solution that basically means, 'catch all recoverable exceptions"?

My question is; is the above code considered good Scala style, is it "safe", meaning better than catching only the string to Date cast exception.

Comment: If you really need to use the `try / catch` _control_, I would recommend you to catch [**NonFatal**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/control/NonFatal$.html) instead, since **Exception** will include fatals too _(this is true in Java also)_. - However, usually in Scala, you would use the [**Try** _monad_](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Try.html) instead. Which, internally will catch any non-fatal exceptions and provides a more functional api to interact with them.

Comment: Yes, I've seen monad functional usage and will convert eventually. I see in your link that any fatal errors do not create a `Failure` and also bypass `Success`. For fatal errors this is likely what we want in the code above.

Comment: So, does that solve your question or not? - Being honest, It is still not clear to me what was your question.

Comment: The question was partly about style and partly about the use of `Exception` as a catchall. You answered both and I would give you credit if you put it in an answer. @Mario Galic gave a good tutorial but it wasn't what I asked.

Comment: I believe Mario's answer is more complete of what I would have written, also he included in his answer a suggestion I made. And also answers the _catchall_ part at the end. So I believe his answer should be the accepted one. Nevertheless, I am glad I helped too :)

Answer (score 9):

Addressing the style aspect of the question, `Try`, as suggested by @LuisMiguelMejiaSuarez, provides a more idiomatic Scala style like so

```
Try(eventTimeString.as[Date]) match {
  case Success(eventTimeDate) => // work with eventTimeDate
  case Failure(e: IllegalArgumentException) => // work with e
  case Failure(e: NullPointerException) => // work with e
  ...
  case Failure(e) => // work with e
}
```

Syntactically it appears not much different, however conceptually it is quite a shift because `Success` and `Failure` represent regular *values* as opposed to some exceptional *control-structure*. `Success` is a value like `7` is value, whilst `try-catch` is more like `while` or `if-else` control facility.

Wrapping any library call that might throw in `Try`, provided by, say, Java libraries, we could make use of for-yield sugar to chain calls like so

```
for {
  a <- Try(foo)
  b <- Try(bar)
  c <- Try(qux)
} yield {
  // work with a, b and c
}
```

where

```
def foo: Int = {
  throw new TimeoutException("foo")
  42
}

def bar: String = {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("bar")
  "hello"
}

def qux: Boolean = {
  throw new NullPointerException("qux")
  true
}
```

We can read this chain sequentially without having to interrupt our flow of thought and try to understand how some exceptional control structure fits into the algorithm.

Regarding safety aspect of the question, arguably, we should not catch fatal exception such as `LinkageError`, and indeed `Try` does not match the following exceptions

```
VirtualMachineError
ThreadDeath
InterruptedException
LinkageError
ControlThrowable
```

as shown by the way it is [constructed](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/a73bacc2499170688eda6e0b2a912be5524da737/src/library/scala/util/Try.scala#L211)

```
object Try {
  def apply[T](r: => T): Try[T] =
    try Success(r) catch {
      case NonFatal(e) => Failure(e)
    }
}
```

where [`NonFatal`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/a73bacc2499170688eda6e0b2a912be5524da737/src/library/scala/util/control/NonFatal.scala#L35) is

```
object NonFatal {
   def apply(t: Throwable): Boolean = t match {
     case _: VirtualMachineError | _: ThreadDeath | _: InterruptedException | _: LinkageError | _: ControlThrowable => false
     case _ => true
   }

  def unapply(t: Throwable): Option[Throwable] = if (apply(t)) Some(t) else None
}
```

Comment: so the implication is that `Exception` will catch some of those fatal errors ignored in `NonFatal`?

Comment: Can you show how `Exception` differs from `NonFatal`. This seems very important and is still slightly unclear.

Comment: `NonFatal` catches all `Throwable`s except for the above mention five which it semantically considers fatal. `Exception` extends `Throwable`, thus it is one level below `Throwable`, and it does not catch any `Error`s. For example, `NonFatal` would catch `AssertionError` whilst `Exception` would not.