# What is the difference between Exception and Throwable classes?

Tags: scala, exception

I am new to the exception handling in Scala. Java states that `Exception` is the superclass of all exceptions. Similarly `Throwable` is the superclass of all exceptions in Scala. But recently I have come across "Exception" class being used in a lot of Scala codes too.
Can you please tell me the difference between `Throwable` class and `Exception` class in Scala.

Comment: Exception is used because you normally don´t want to catch Errors, and Throwable is the superclass behind Exceptions and Errors

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, Scala reuses exception structure from Java (so [Throwable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) comes from Java). The class hierarchy looks like this:

```
         Throwable
            |
    ------------------
    |                |
  Error          Exception
    |                |
  errors             |
             -------------------
             |                 |
     runtime exceptions   checked exceptions
```

*Throwable* is the superclass of all errors in Java.

*Error* is the superclass for errors, that are not recoverable like *VirtualMachineError* or *ThreadDeath*. Errors can be intercepted using *try-catch*, but usually, it's not a good practice.

Child classes of *Exception* are exceptions, that are intended to handled programmatically by intercepting them using *try-catch*.

Java also makes the difference between *runtime* and *checked* exceptions, that *checked* exception need to be mandatorily handled by *try-catch*.

Scala though handles all exceptions as *runtime*, so intercepting them is [voluntary](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_exception_handling).

Scala has also extractor named *NonFatal*, which can be used to pattern match non-fatal Throwables. For example:

```
try {
  // dangerous stuff
} catch {
  //will NOT match fatal errors like VirtualMachineError, ThreadDeath, LinkageError etc.
  case NonFatal(e) => log.error(e, "Something not that bad.") 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof Atłasik, your explanation sums up everything I wanted to know.!! :)

Comment: Errors can _also_ be caught, you just don't want to do that. Scala also has https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/util/control/NonFatal$.html for its own version of error/exception distinction.

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik Do you mind if I link in my answer (here in the comments) to [Is it safe to catch an Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56385613/5205022) as I believe it complements your answer?

Comment: @MarioGalic Sure, no problem.